# How can I capture an incoming email with ASP.net-mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I would like to write a web system that can capture and parse incoming emails, traditionally the web system I write are asp.net-mvc, running in a cloud hosted environment like AppHarbour or Azure.

How can I leverage those (and potentially my DNS) to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely this isn't quite easy nor straightforward. Your typical ASP.NET app listens for HTTP requests, not incoming email requests which land on a different port and use an entirely different protocol than your typical HTTP application understands.

The best bet is to leverage some sort of email recieving service which is capable of translating your incoming email into a HTTP request an ASP.NET app running on azure or appharbor could understand.

Comment: do you know of any services that do this?